# Add style to CompletionProposal in Eclipse RCP (Content assist)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, content-assist

I'm creating a custom content assist for an editor, this is how I'm creating the proposals:

```
@Override
public ICompletionProposal[] computeCompletionProposals(ITextViewer viewer, int offset) {
    String test = "Test";
    ContextInformation contextInfo = new ContextInformation("Context display test", "information display test");
    CompletionProposal proposal = new CompletionProposal(test,
            offset, 
            0, 
            test.length(),
            Activator.getImage("icons/sample.png"), 
            test,
            contextInfo,
            "Additional info");
    return new ICompletionProposal[] {proposal}; 
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Which is fine, but for example, in the content assist of the Java editor, they are using colors such as blue and gray:

[image]

I know there is a class called `StyledText` that could help but I can't find a good example to use it in combination with `CompletionProposal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension interface `ICompletionProposalExtension6` supports styled display strings. Its sole method `getStyledDisplayString()` must return a `StyledString` that is used for display.

Instead of creating an instance of `CompletionProposal` you would have to implement your own `ICompletionProposal` that also implements the above mentioned extension. For example:

```java
class StyledCompletionProposal 
    implements ICompletionProposal, ICompletionProposalExtension6 
{

  ...

  @Override
  public StyledString getStyledDisplayString() {
    return new StyledString("test").append(" [10%]", Styler.QUALIFIER_STYLER);
  }

}
```

In addition, the content assistant must be configured to enable *coloured labels*. For editors, this is usually done in `SourceViewerConfiguration::getContentAssistant`:

```java
ContentAssistant contentAssistant = new ContentAssistant();
contentAssistant.enableColoredLabels(true);
```

Comment: I tried to extend `CompletionProposal` but it is not possible `The type CustomProposal cannot subclass the final class CompletionProposal` so besides implementing `ICompletionProposalExtension6` I also implemented `ICompletionProposal`, I implemented the necessary methods from both interfaces including `getStyledDisplayString` and then used the new class instead of `CompletionProposal` but this method is never called, looks like the framework is only using `getDisplayString` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete answer, I've updated it with the missing bits.